# Break do while loop when output condition is met

Tags: java

I want to print 2 random values, such as "1, 3" so long as the two numbers printed are not equal.

The loop should break when the 2 numbers that print are the same.

I have created the following piece of code, but I am unsure as to what the condition would be in order to break the statement when the 2 numbers that output are the same. Can someone please help out? Thank you!

```
    Random random = new Random();

    do
    {                              
        int randomInt = random.nextInt(6);
        int randomInt2 = random.nextInt(6);
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(randomInt) + ", " + Integer.toString(randomInt2));
    }
    while ( /* problem */);
```

Comment: Declare your two int variables _outside_ of the do/while loop...

Comment: Hi, the problem is that if I declare the variables outside the loop, they will always be the same.

Comment: Of course not! What makes you think that? I tell you to _declare_ them, not to **assign** them!

Comment: I don't thing you need that loop at all.

Comment: Try seeding your "Random" instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would just be `while(randomInt!=randomInt2)`. And, as was said in the comments, you should declare the variables outside of the loop. You don't have to initialize them - just say

```
int randomInt,randomInt2;
```

and that will be enough.

Comment: "You don't have to declare them" <-- err, `int randomInt,randomInt2;` is a declaration ;)

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I cannot use that condition if the variables are inside the loop and if I declare them outside the loop,  they will always be the same.

Comment: @user2917239 read my answer in the comments; you seem to be mixing declaration and assignment

Comment: @fge: I meant "initialize", not "declare". Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
int randomInt, randomInt2;

do {
    randomInt = random.nextInt(6);
    randomInt2 = random.nextInt(6);
    System.out.println(randomInt + ", " + randomInt2);
} while (randomInt != randomInt2);
```

---

To clear up one of your confusions:

```
int i; // declaration
i = 2; // assignment
int i = 2; // declaration _and_ assignment
```